# Remove row from chart range using office interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am inserting a chart into a word document using the c# office interop.

I am inserting the chart into the document then accessing the ActiveSheet from the charts associated workbook to change the values of the cells in order to display the data I want. The code that I currently have working can be seen below.

```
 Application application = new ApplicationClass();

            var paragraph = CreateParagraph();

            var chart = application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart(XlChartType.xlColumnClustered, paragraph.Range);

            var activeSheet = chart.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet;

            activeSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "YTD LM Sales";
            activeSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "YTD LM Budget Value";
            activeSheet.Cells[4, 1] = "YTD LY LM Sales";
            activeSheet.Rows[5] = null;

            for (int i = 0; i <= results.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                var sale = results.ElementAt(i);

                activeSheet.Cells[1, i + 2] = sale.FinancialPLN;
                activeSheet.Cells[2, i + 2] = GetStringValueOfNumber(sale.YtdLmSales);
                activeSheet.Cells[3, i + 2] = GetStringValueOfNumber(sale.YtdLmBudgetValue);
                activeSheet.Cells[4, i + 2] = GetStringValueOfNumber(sale.YtdLyLmSales);
            }
```

However, by default the chart that is created has 4 rows in the active sheet giving 4 series on the graph. The problem I am having is that I only have 3 rows of actual data that I want to use.

As such the 4th default row is getting shown in the chart with some default values.

I want to remove this row all together and make sure that the chart does not show it. I have tried nulling the values out but then the chart just has empty space where the series should be.

Does anyone know how to either set the range for a chart created in this way or simply remove a row from the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something along the lines of:

```
chart.Chart.SeriesCollection(4).Delete();
```

You need the chart.Chart because chart is an InlineShape and doesn't know about Chart behavior.

I found the SeriesCollection(4).Delete() behavior by recording a macro in Excel and deleting a series from a chart, then viewing the code.

Comment: Unfortunately SeriesCollection is not a valid property of the chart object. I have had a look around for a property of a similar name and have been unable to find one

Comment: The SeriesCollection is not available on the chart.Chart object either

Comment: It works on my end, I am referencing .NET 4.0 client / 4.5, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 14.0.0.0 / 15.0.0.0, and Word 2010. How about you?

Comment: Check these out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193558(v=office.14).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178382(v=office.12).aspx ...